Dynamically add color in ion-card text based on regex
I want to add a span around some text when a # or a @ is detected so I can change the color to make it look like usernames and hashtags in twitter. My code looks like this:
TS FILE:
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.glyphService.getAllGlyphs().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.items = result;
        // sort by rune id so list is newest to oldest
        this.items.sort((a, b) => Number(b.rune) - Number(a.rune));
        for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
          this.items[i].glyph_content = this.replaceIt(this.items[i].glyph_content);
          console.log(this.items[i])
        }
        console.log(this.items)
      }
    );
  }

  replaceIt = (str: string) => {
    const regex = /\B([\#\@][a-zA-Z]+\b)(?!;)/g;
    const subst = `<span style="color:blue">$1</span>`;
    const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
    return result;
 }

HTML FILE:
  <ion-card *ngFor="let item of items" >
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>&#64;{{item.username}}</ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-subtitle>{{item.glyph_date}}</ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      {{item.glyph_content}}
    </ion-card-content>
 </ion-card>

I’m successfully replacing the text like I want to, however it’s just winding up as text instead actual tags and looks like this:
test <span style="color:blue">@hey</span> <span style="color:blue">@uh</span> wow <span style="color:blue">#ah</span> words <span style="color:blue">#oh</span>
Is there a way for me to change my code so I’m actually dynamically wrapping the target text in real spans like I want? Is it possible to use *ngIf in some creative way here?

We need to use DomSanitizer and [innerHtml] for this to work.
In your component.ts file:
// TS File
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  items: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private glyphService: GlyphService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.glyphService.getAllGlyphs().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.items = result;
        // sort by rune id so list is newest to oldest
        this.items.sort((a, b) => Number(b.rune) - Number(a.rune));
        for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
          this.items[i].glyph_content_html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
            this.replaceIt(this.items[i].glyph_content)
          );
        }
        console.log(this.items);
      }
    );
  }

  replaceIt = (str: string): string => {
    const regex = /\B([\#\@][a-zA-Z]+\b)(?!;)/g;
    const subst = `<span style="color:blue">$1</span>`;
    const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
    return result;
  }
}

In your HTML:
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-title>&#64;{{item.username}}</ion-card-title>
    <ion-card-subtitle>{{item.glyph_date}}</ion-card-subtitle>
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content [innerHTML]="item.glyph_content_html">
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>


This worked, thanks! I see you are importing SafeHtml, I understand I'll need to make sure the html is sanitized in the future if I allow a user to input text, so I'll look into that. Appreciate it mate!

If you find the answer useful, please upvote it so that others can also find it easily and it will be on the top
